# After wrapping a component with Connect in Redux, passing props to the component causes an error of the ts type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

```
          <Logo collapsed={this.props.collapsed}/>
```

The error message is：

```
TS2322: Type  { collapsed: boolean; }  is not assignable to type
(IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<{}, never>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<ClassAttributes<Component<{}, any, any>>, "ref" | "key">)
Property  collapsed  does not exist on type
(IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<{}, never>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<ClassAttributes<Component<{}, any, any>>, "ref" | "key">)
```

This is the props definition for this component =》

```
    interface IProps {
  collapsed: boolean;
  switchCurrentSiderMenuKey: (currentMenu: string) => void
}

const Logo: React.SFC<IProps> = ({collapsed,switchCurrentSiderMenuKey }) => {
```

I made sure that there would be no error in wrapping the component without using connect.

This is the connet internal implementation of the package =》

```
ConnectGlobal(Page: React.ComponentType) {
    const mapStateToProps = createGlobalMapStateToPropsFunc();
    const mapDispatchToProps = createGlobalMapDispatchToPropsFunc();
    return connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(Page);
  }
---------------------------------
export function createGlobalMapStateToPropsFunc(): any {
  return (globalState: any): any => {
    return {globalState};
  };
}

export function createGlobalMapDispatchToPropsFunc(): any {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch, ownProps: any): object => {
    if (Const.isTest && Framework.isDebugModel()) {
      return format(new GlobalActionDispatcher(dispatch, ownProps, new GlobalServiceMock()));
    }
    return format(new GlobalActionDispatcher(dispatch, ownProps, new GlobalService()));
  };
}
```

this is the vison

```
 "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-custom-scrollbars": "4.2.1",
        "react-dom": "16.13.1",
        "react-draggable": "4.4.3",
        "react-lazyload": "3.2.0",
        "react-loadable": "5.5.0",
        "react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
        "react-redux": "7.1.0",
        "react-resizable": "3.0.4",
        "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
        "react-transition-group": "4.4.1",
        "react-viewer": "^3.2.2",
        "recharts": "1.6.2",
        "reconnecting-websocket": "4.4.0",
        "redux": "4.0.4",
```

i dont know how can do

Comment: Sorry, we can't address issues in code we can't see. Can you [edit] your post to include a more complete description of the issue or problem you have, a complete [mcve] of the relevant code, and if there are any errors, the complete error message(s) and any accompany error stacktrace(s)? Please also review the [help](/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.